# Comparing csv file to Folder file

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I am trying to compare a csv file with the following information:

```
User1,ID1
User2,ID2
User3,ID3
```

to a folder file with many folders that have the same names as the first column of the csv file.

So far I have this code but it is not working.

```
$input = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\csv\list.csv' -Header "Users","ID"

$folder = Get-ChildItem H:\Test | Sort-Object name

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $input.Users -DifferenceObject $folder -IncludeEqual

if(($input.Users).SideIndicator -eq "=="){
    echo "true"
}else{
    echo "false"
}
```

Ultimately, my goal is to compare the <s>header</s>column of the csv to the folders and see if it have the same name, if so, add new permission to the matched folder with the ID from the second <s>header</s>column of the CSV. I understand it's a lot more than what I have in my code, but baby steps.

Comment: Why the compare? You would have to iterate the result. I'd iterate the csv and do a `Test-Path` with the user name

Comment: My logic was to compare the csv file to the folders to see if the user matches the folder name, then add new permission to the folder with the connected ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the compare? You would have to iterate the result. I'd iterate the csv and do a Test-Path with the user name.

```
$BaseDir = 'H:\Test'
$input = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\csv\list.csv' -Header "User","ID"

ForEach-Object ($Item in $input){
    $UserPath = Join-Path $BaseDir $Item.User
    If (Test-Path $UserPath -PathType Container){
        "User {0}  ID {1} Folder {2} exists" -f $Item.User,$UserPath,$Item.ID
    } else {
        # possibly create the folder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you do `Get-ChildItem` the result is an array of objects. Those are `dotnet` objects with all their properties, methods etc available for you.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Directory
foreach($line in $csv) { 
    $folder = $folders | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $line.Name}
    if($folder -ne $null){
        #ACL magic goes here, there are a number of articles on this
    }
}
```